# c#: how to force trailing zero in numeric format string?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need to display float as

```
1.00
1.50
1.55
1.60
```

The following is what I see using f2 format.

```
1.
1.5
1.55
1.6
```

Is there a way to force the trailing 0 to appear?

(I'm using a DevExpress SpinEdit control and trying to set the display and edit format.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
yourNumber.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: this one adds unnecessary commas for thousands, does not perfectly fit in cases with larger numbers

Answer (score 16):

You can use syntax like this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", n)
```

Answer (score 5):

For future reference,

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Much better link: deals with trailing zeroes etc

Answer (score 5):

On those rare occasions I need to formatting, I go here:

http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 4):

```
spinEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
spinEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "C2";
```

In the future, though, I would recommended searching [Dev Express' knowledge base](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/) or emailing support (support@devexpress.com).  They'll be able to answer your question in about a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with string interpolation (note that this is C# 6 and above):

```
double num = 98765.4;
Console.WriteLine($"{num:0.00}"); //Replace "0.00" with "N2" if you want thousands separators
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had a variable called "myNumber" of type double:

```
double myNumber = 1520;
```

Instead of:

```
myNumber.ToString("N2"); // returns "1,520.00"
```

I would opt for:

```
myNumber.ToString("0.00"); // returns "1520.00"
```

since N2 will add "," thousands separators, which can often cause problems downstream.